# How to get retrofit response one by one on button click to populate on activity?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I am developing a quiz app in which I am getting questions, 4 options and its correct answer using `RETROFIT` library. There are multiple questions and answers which I want to populate on my `QuizActivity`. The activity contains two buttons next and previous to fetch next or previous question with its options depending on the respective `onClick` event.I am getting correct `JSON` response with `retrofit` but not able to find out the way to achieve my goal to populate the response on `QuizActivity` using button click event. I have researched a lot for this solution and finally asking the question. Thanks in advance.

Following is the code of `QuizActivity.java` :

```
package com.oskartechnologies.safetymodule;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView question;
    RadioButton optiona, optionb, optionc, optiond;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    Button next, previous;

int questionsCount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    optiona = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.optiona);
    optionb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.optionb);
    optiond = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.optionc);
    optiond = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.optiond);
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionView);
    previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevButton);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);

    previous.setOnClickListener(this);

    getQuiz();
}

private void getQuiz() {
    final BlockingQueue<JSONArray> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://netcafe.oskartechnologies.com/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    APiService service = retrofit.create(APiService.class);
    Call<List<QuizModule>> call = service.getQuizData("1");
    Log.d("retrofit", call + "");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<QuizModule>>() {
        List<QuizModule> list;

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<QuizModule>> call, Response<List<QuizModule>> response) {
            Log.d("Response", response.message().toString());
            list = response.body();
            //questionsCount = list.size();
          //QuizModule q = new QuizModule();

         //for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                //String questiontext = list.get(i).getQuestion();
               //question.setText(questiontext);
            //}

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<QuizModule>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Failure", t.getMessage().toString());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.nextButton) {
        if (questionsCount > 0) {

        }
    }
 }
}
```

Following is the `POJO` class :

```
package com.oskartechnologies.safetymodule;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by Wasim on 24/01/2018.
 */

public class QuizModule {

   @SerializedName("question")
   @Expose
   private String question;

   @SerializedName("option_a")
   @Expose
   private String optiona;

   @SerializedName("option_b")
   @Expose
   private String optionb;

   @SerializedName("option_c")
   @Expose
   private String optionc;

   @SerializedName("option_d")
   @Expose
   private String optiond;

   @SerializedName("answer")
   @Expose
   private String answer;

   public String getQuestion() {
      return question;
   }

   public void setQuestion(String question) {
      this.question = question;
   }

   public String getOptiona() {
      return optiona;
   }

   public void setOptiona(String optiona) {
       this.optiona = optiona;
   }

   public String getOptionb() {
      return optionb;
   }

   public void setOptionb(String optionb) {
       this.optionb = optionb;
   }

   public String getOptionc() {
       return optionc;
   }

   public void setOptionc(String optionc) {
      this.optionc = optionc;
   }

   public String getOptiond() {
       return optiond;
   }

   public void setOptiond(String optiond) {
       this.optiond = optiond;
   }

   public String getAnswer() {
       return answer;
   }

   public void setAnswer(String answer) {
      this.answer = answer;
   }
 }
```

Following is the `JSON` response I am getting :

```
[
    {
        "question": "If a cream coloured band is located over the fire extinguisher, it indicates that the fire extinguisher is which of the following?",
        "option_a": "Water",
        "option_b": "Dry Powder",
        "option_c": "Foam",
        "option_d": "Carbon Dioxide",
        "answer": "Foam"
    },
    {
        "question": "Which type of fire extinguish do you use to fight an electrical fire if a carbon dioxide extinguisher is unavailable?",
        "option_a": "Water",
        "option_b": "Wet Chemical",
        "option_c": "Foam",
        "option_d": "Dry Powder",
        "answer": "Dry Powder"
    }
]
```

Comment: Once you get the response you should do `list.get(0)` and populate your Views. When user presses next you increment `questionCount` and do again `list.get(questionCount)` and fill the Views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `List<QuizModule> list` a global variable so you can access it in your onClick method.
Also add a global counter to keep track of question index: `int counter`

Then in your onClick:

```
if (questionsCount > 0) {
    String questiontext = list.get(counter).getQuestion();
    question.setText(questiontext);
    counter++;
}
```